# Unable to successfully add plugin for google-play services

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play-services

I am using the same gradle file for my project and app.

When I add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of my `build.gradle`,  gradle does not build properly.

I am unsure why this is the case.

Plus, I am trying to integrate my client app with GCM and Pubnub. In Pubnub's documentation it states that a `<service>` appears in `AndroidManifest.xml` if google services was added correctly.

Here is the source: [https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-06-24-sending-receiving-android-push-notifications-with-gcm-google-cloud-messaging/](http://Pubnub%20Integration%20with%20GCM)

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10109" android:versionName="1.1.9" package="com.healthpalsinc.patient" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService" />
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" />
        <provider android:authorities="com..provider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.healthpalsinc.patient" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="com.healthpalsinc.patient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.healthpalsinc.patient.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```js
/*
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
*/

// GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        }
    } else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0+'
        }
    } else {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: 'CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
apply from: "phonegap-plugin-push/patient-push.gradle"
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
if (ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
}
if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = 'debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = 'release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps << {
    println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
    println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
    println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
    println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
    println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
    println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
    println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
    android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
        println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
    }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'Patient App Android Key'
            keyPassword 'healthpals'
            storeFile file('/Users/spyapali/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-23/android/security/keystore/android.jks')
            storePassword 'shalu1129'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        versionCode 10109
        versionName '1.1.9'
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        productFlavors {
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", ""
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "x86", ""
                }
            }
            all {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "all", ""
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (!cdvVersionCode) {
        def minSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion ?: privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("minSdkVersion")
        // Vary versionCode by the two most common API levels:
        // 14 is ICS, which is the lowest API level for many apps.
        // 20 is Lollipop, which is the lowest API level for the updatable system webview.
        if (minSdkVersion >= 20) {
            defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
        } else if (minSdkVersion >= 14) {
            defaultConfig.versionCode += 8
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = "Patient App Android Key"
                keyPassword = "healthpals"
                // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = "/Users/spyapali/Library/Android/sdk/sources/android-23/android/security/keystore/android.jks"
                storePassword = "shalu1129"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
            debug {
                debuggable True
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }
    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }
    productFlavors {
        config {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        flavor {
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 10109
            versionName '1.1.9'
        }
        blackberry {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            versionName '1.1.9'
            versionCode 101091
        }
        guava {
            versionCode 101093
            versionName '1.1.9'
        }
        passionfruit {
            versionCode 101094
            versionName '1.1.9'
        }
        mango {
            versionCode 101095
            versionName '1.1.9'
        }
        strawberry {
            versionCode 101098
            versionName '1.1.9'
        }
        banana {
            versionCode 101100
            versionName '1.1.10'
        }
        lemon {
            versionCode 101110
            versionName '1.1.11'
        }
        lychee {
            versionCode 101120
            versionName '1.1.12'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.2'
    compile 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0"
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
        if (task.name == 'validateReleaseSigning') {
            promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
        }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is the error I'm getting:

Error: Unable to load class 'com.google.gson.JsonObject'.

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

1. Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
2. Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart). Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
3. In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

I've tried all the above and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated :). Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you provide your AndroidManifest.xml and your build.gradle file?

Comment: Yeah provide those files and we'll find the problem

Comment: May you provide the error in log?

Comment: @vgarzom, sure! What do you mean by that? Thanks!

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053925/unable-to-load-class-com-google-gson-jsonobject) which suggested to add `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'` to the top-level build file dependencies. Also make sure that you are using Android Studio 1.5 or above. Here's a [related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38420409/add-google-analytics-to-android-project-error-unable-to-load-class-com-googl) which might help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the references @abielita! I'm now able to successfully compile `build.gradle` with the `google-play-services` plugin!

Answer (score 0):

I think that `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` must be in your `build.gradle` file, not in manifest.

Comment: Yes, it is! I'm still having the same issue though. I'll post the error soon.